# List is empty but shouldn't be

Tags: python, django

```
membership = GroupMembers.objects.filter(profile=profile.id, accepted__isnull=False).values_list('group', flat=True)
```

When I don't use values_list, I have one element in membership. But I just want to have a list with all the attributes "group" of the GroupMembers models. So I learned about values_list. However, now this will give me an empty list. What is wrong?

EDIT:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='profile_id')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, max_length=500)
    group_set = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through='GroupMembers')
    file_set = models.ManyToManyField(File, blank=True)
    user_code = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class GroupMembers(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='group_profile_id')
        group = models.ForeignKey(Group, db_column='group_id')
        profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, db_column='profile_id')
        rank = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
        invited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        accepted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)
        rejected = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: is `group` supposed to be a foreign key?

Comment: When you don't use `values_list`, what does the one element have for `group`?  Could that one element have `None` for `group`?

Comment: @sedavidw But then shouldn't the return value be `[None, ]` in this case?

Comment: @Sayse group is supposed to be a foreign key

Comment: @ShangWang I think thats the case

Comment: Please show your models.

Comment: @ShangWang can't find it in the Django doc (still looking) but I think it doesn't return anything for a null foreign key. @Dennis could you tell us what actually is in the membership element without using `values_list`...would be easy to verify...

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done.

Comment: Why does it need to be a `values_list`? This is usually used when you need to only retrieve certain fields, almost pointless when you want all of them

Comment: @sedavidw GroupMembers objects AS in the models. In this case 1 object.

Comment: @Sayse because i want to have a list of the ids , not of all GroupMembers. And group is the ID oft the group

Comment: @DennisvonEich perhaps my question wasn't clear.  If I understand you right, if you do `membership = GroupMembers.objects.filter(profile=profile.id, accepted__isnull=False)`, `membership` has one instance of a `GroupMember` in it.  What happens when you do membership[0].group

Comment: No, it has all instances oft groupmember of a user. GroupMembers is the link between member and group. Thats why i call it membership. If a user is in 4 groups. There are 4 GroupMembers instances for him

Comment: And what are the values for `group` in all of those instances.  i.e. what is the output of  `[gm.group for gm in membership]`

Comment: This is the ID of the group. It is a foreignkey to the group model

Comment: @DennisvonEich did you actually run the code?  I asked you to do the query without `values_list` and pull out all instances of `Group`.  What came out?

Comment: @sedavidw how to 'pull out' all instances oft group?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103127/discussion-between-sedavidw-and-dennis-von-eich).